# How to prettify JS code inside <script> tag in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, firefox

I'm trying to debug JS code inside `<script>` tag. So I need to set some breakpoints but I'm unable to do that since Google Chrome doesn't prettify code inside `<script>` tag. When I press "Prettify" button the browser is just prettifying HTML code and isn't touching JS code. Also the same problem is present in Mozilla Firefox. Is there a way to force the browser to prettify JS code?

[image: Not prettified JS]

Comment: Without prettifying, you could add a `debugger;` line in your code which will pause code and go to chrome devtools where the line is written

Comment: @UlysseBN, is it possible to do this if the website isn't mine? I see the changes made in "Elements" tab aren't reflected in "Sources". And also that line of JS code is consisting of many lines, I need to set breakpoints at some of them.

Comment: No it is not. Even if you achieve to prettify, I'm not sure you would be able to set code breakpoint. Although you could download the page with a tool like curl, and work on it locally. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @UlysseBN, I was trying to find out where the website is getting information for building calendar. Nevermind, I already solved that. By the way, I can set breakpoint directly to this line of code.

Comment: Then you should [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that anybody can know :)

Comment: @UlysseBN, I can't. I simply changed the way to solve the problem with calendar. Problem that I asked here is still unsolved, I just don't need it to be solved anymore.